# Do readied spells take effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The rules for [readying spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Ready) says the following:

> When you ready a spell, you cast it as normal but hold its energy, which you release with your reaction when the trigger occurs.

I saw this argument on reddit today:

> The rules say you cast the spell as normal, so the spell takes effect immediately. I have no idea what the energy stuff is about, but it says you cast the spell as normal.

It seems to me like the intention is for the spell to only take effect when the trigger occurs and the caster chooses to activate the spell. I don't have any doubt that's how it's supposed to work.

However I think the reddit user has a point, the whole "energy" thing is a bit ill-defined. Is there a concrete text in the rules that proves that "holding back energy and releasing it" change the timing of a spell being cast?

Comment: So what was the alternative? You can't ready a spell at all?

Comment: @enkryptor I don't know, I think it's just another ridiculous reddit argument, I didn't ask.

Comment: So basically we don't know what that user suggests, but we have to find out if he is correct?

Comment: @enkryptor If you'd like. I'd be happy to have a mechanical answer as to what "holding back and releasing energy" means, which I believe MivaScott provided below; "A spell is a discrete magical effect, a single shaping of the magical energies [...] then releases them to unleash the desired effect"

Comment: @enkryptor It is not necessary for an alternative to be well defined for an interpretation to be criticized.

Answer (score 10):

### It's in the PHB

Under [Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#WhatIsaSpell):

> A spell is a discrete magical effect, a single shaping of the magical **energies** that suffuse the multiverse into a specific, limited expression. In casting a spell, a character carefully plucks at the invisible strands of raw magic suffusing the world, pins them in place in a particular pattern, sets them vibrating in a specific way, and then releases them to unleash the desired effect — **in most cases, all in the span of seconds.**

And under [Ready](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#Ready) (combat action):

> When you ready a spell, you cast it as normal but hold its energy, which you **release with your reaction when the trigger occurs**. To be readied, a spell must have a casting time of 1 action, and holding onto the spell's magic requires concentration (explained in chapter 10).

The spell must have a casting time of one action, so spells that take longer, or are bonus actions are disqualified. So are reactions, but they already have a trigger.

So per the description, the caster shapes magical energy which normally takes a single action. But in this case, you hold that energy (which is the magic). Once the trigger occurs you can release the energy (or you lose concentration and the energy dissipates without effect).

The other key is that you "release with your reaction". Except under edge cases, the character's reaction does not happen on their turn. It happens as a trigger to someone else's turn. So there is a built-in delay; cast on your turn and release on someone else's.

Comment: "Once the trigger occurs (or you lose concentration) you can release the energy" makes it sound like you can release the energy and cause the spell to take its full effects when losing concentration. I'd suggest some sort of clarifying edit since you can't do that. Some quotes from the Sage Advice Compendium may also help: "Your target must be within range when you take a readied action, not when you first ready it." As well as a lengthy description of Readying *dispel magic*

Comment: Good answer, "releases [the energies] to unleash the desired effect" is the key phrase!

Comment: @Medix2 I think the question is essentially answered by the spellcasting quote, so if anything needs clarifying or further discussion it would be best to remove it, rather than adding extra tangential information.

Comment: @gszavae, when I originally answered I just had the Spellcasting quote as i thought your question was about "energy" being undefined. Then i reread and thought the question was about changing the timing of the spell so I added the rest about being a reaction and happening on someone else's turn. So now both basis are covered

Comment: @Medix2, I updated the phrasing about losing concentration. Good catch